# Sending pointers as a parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am kinda new to C and I'm not sure how pointer works. The first example works the way i want it to do, a and b changes to 1 and c does not.

```
void pointers_and_variables(int *a, int *b, int c)
{
   a[0] = 1;
   b[0] = 1;
   c = 1;
}

int main()
{
   int a = 0;
   int b = 0;
   int c = 0;

   pointers_and_variables(&a,&b,c);

   printf("a:%d b:%d c:%d", a,b,c);

   return 0;
}
```

What I do not understand is why I cant change

```
int a = 0
int b = 0
int c = 0

pointers_and_variables(&a,&b,c);
```

to

```
int *a = 0
int *b = 0
int c = 0

pointers_and_variables(a,b,c);
```

Comment: What's the question? "What are pointers" or "what does this program do"? Note that this program is written in a very peculiar and inefficient way because it uses recursion rather than a simple loop.

Answer (score 2):

**It calculates the number of negative, positive entries as well as zeros in array a.**

```
      stat(a, size-1, neg, zer, pos);
```

It uses recursion to achieve the objective. Say size = 10, then the function will be called with

```
  stat(a, 9, neg, zer, pos);
```

since `size` is not equal to `0` (first `if` won't be entered) and `else` part will be called. This will happen till it becomes `size == 0`. i.e

```
  stat(a, 8, neg, zer, pos);
  stat(a, 7, neg, zer, pos);
   ...
  stat(a, 0, neg, zer, pos);
```

When `stat` is called with `size` as 0, value of `neg`, `zer`, `pos` will be set as 0 since the `if` becomes true. Then the function is exited, and go backs to the line after the function call

```
  stat(a, 0, neg, zer, pos);
```

that is,

```
      if (a[size-1] < 0)
            *neg = *neg + 1;
      else if (a[size-1] == 0)
            *zer = *zer + 1;
      else
            *pos = *pos + 1;
```

Here. It checks whether the element of the array `a[size-1] < 0` (negative entry) or `a[size-1] == 0` or `else` (i.e. positive entry). i.e, whether the number is positive, zero or negative. Then positive (`pos`), negative (`neg`), or zero (`zer`) counter is incremented respectively using pointers. `*zer` points to the values stored in the pointer. To learn basics about pointer see [this reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

Since you pass the pointer to the call, the `*pos` in all the function call points to the same memory and as a result, the latest value will be available for all the calls.

Assuming all numbers in array are positive, the *pos value will be like following:

For `size=0`, `*pos` will be `0`

For `size=1`, `*pos` will be `*pos +1` (which is `0+1`)

...

For `size=N`, `*pos` will be `*pos +1` (which will be `N-1+1`)

Like in the comment pointed out by **@John Bollinger**, it is analogous to

```
int i = 0;
i = i + 1;
```

Comment: Okey I think I understand, but the last thing I dont get is if pos adding upp everytime its a positve, like first pos = 1 then pos = 1+ 1 ... or how does that work considering its pointers

Comment: Yes, since it's pointer it *pos always points to the same location. as a result, when size becomes 0, the *pos will be 0, for the call size=1, *pos will be 0, for the call size=2, *pos will be *pos+1 i.e 1 and so on...

Comment: @AdamRöhr, no pointer arithmetic is involved.  Consider `*pos = *pos + 1`, for example.  The sub-expression `*pos` represents the `int` to which pointer `pos` points.  The overall expression adds 1 to the value of that `int`, and overwrites it with the result.  It is analogous to `int i; /* ... assign value to i ... */ i = i + 1;`.

Comment: The thing that I I don't really understand is *pos = *pos + 1, I thought that meant adding the address by 4, example 1004 to 1008. Do you mean it adding how many positive integers it is in the array? Will *pos store 5 if its 5 positive integers in the array?

Comment: *pos points to the value stored in the memory address of pos. Say pos is a pointer to a memory 1008. then *pos means the value stored inside that memory 1008. *pos = 1 means value of 1 will be in memory 1008. *pos = *pos+1 means, adding 1 to the value inside the memory of pos. pos = pos+1 means it will point to the memory 1012 (1008+4 assuming 4 as integer size). That is pointer arithmetic. * points to the value.